# Copy selected data from one worksheet to another with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy selected data from one worksheet to another with Excel VBA. As you can see in my pictures when the **value** is a **0**, the value of the **test_Point** should be written in another worksheet. So I want to **copy** the **test_Point** value of each cell where the **value** is 0.

Source data on `Sheet1`:

[image]

Expected result to be put on `Sheet2`:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to look into this to improve and format your question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, rowIndex As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    'change sheet names as required
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = srcWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    rowIndex = 1

    With srcWS
        For Each rng In .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
            If rng.Value = 0 Then
                destWS.Range("A" & rowIndex).Value = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            End If
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thx, that works good. But I have a question, why do you split with **,** , can I use a function where I exactly copy these values from the worksheet into other sheet ?

Comment: @flowers1234 - You might have observed `str` is a string containing `,` separated values. That's why I've used split before displaying values into sheet.

Comment: @flowers1234 - See edit in answer.

Comment: @flowers1234 - Edited code directly copies value to `Sheet2` without storing them in variable.

Comment: I used the edit code , but it is still with a comma :( @Mrig

Comment: @flowers1234 - Are you using second code that is written after edit?

Comment: @flowers1234 - I've removed previous code. Check whether you are using current code from the answer.

Comment: @flowers1234 - Did it help?

Comment: to be honest , not really. I tried it and i still get a comma. And do you think there is an other way to solve this with "easier" code :-D

Comment: @flowers1234 - This code does not deal in comma's at all. I am able to execute it properly. Is it possible for you share your sheet(with sample data).

Comment: maybe excel does it automatically to turn a point into a comma ?? when I try it with letters it work. I'm confused :/

Comment: @flowers1234 - I am running this code against your sample data in question and its working fine.

Comment: it works now. @Mrig Can you tell me how I can pop up a messagebox after filling a cell with 0

Comment: @flowers1234 - What message do you want to display?

Comment: actually i want to open a Inputbox , when someone fills a cell with 0 , excel automatically should open a Inputbox @Mrig

Comment: @flowers1234 - That's completely new requirement and was not in the scope of current question. So I kindly request you to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just change the name of the sheets/workbooks to whatever you are using, also both workbooks has to be open for this code to run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copydata()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lLr As Long
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbTarget As Workbook

    Set wbSource = Workbooks("WbSource") 'sets source workbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks("WbTarget") 'sets target workbook

Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("SourceSheet") 'sets source worksheet
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("TargetSheet") 'sets target worksheet

lLr = wsSource.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

j = 1

For i = 2 To lLr

    If wsSource.Range("b" & i) = 0 Then

        wsTarget.Range("a" & j).Value = wsSource.Range("A" & i)
        wsTarget.Range("a" & j).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        j = j + 1

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Таке a look at the below example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range

    ' First cell with source data which is to be evaluated
    Set rSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    ' First destination cell where to put result
    Set rDst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    Do
        ' Check if source cell is empty
        If rSrc = "" Then Exit Do
        ' Check if source cell is 0
        If rSrc = 0 Then
            ' Copy value of the cell to the left to the destination
            rDst.Value = rSrc.Offset(0, -1).Value
            ' Move destination down
            Set rDst = rDst.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        ' Move source down
        Set rSrc = rSrc.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I have worksheet one named "aaaa" and second one named "bbbb".

In "bbbb" I put function in one cell:

```
=IF(aaaa!A1<10; "dog"; "cat")
```

This will look in first one in cell A1 if the value is less than 10 and then display some text in cell that is second worksheet.

You need to change the condition in function so that will give you result that you want.

Is this what you were looking for?

Here are some links that also might be helpful regarding accessing values in VBA

- https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-get-values-from-another-sheet-in-excel-using-vba/
- https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure that will work. But I am looking for some vba code. And I thought I can solve this problem maybe with a _for each loop_ . @ghula